# impdp strange ora errors

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I did an import using impdp.

Afterwards I found these errors in the log file.

```
ORA-31693: Table data object "SMTAPP"."XP_ENTITIES_CONFIGS" failed to load/unload and is being skipped due to error:
ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout
ORA-29400: data cartridge error
ORA-26065: check constraint cannot reference column, SYS_NC00005$, in direct path load
```

The table XP_ENTITIES_CONFIGS has an XML datatype column. The table itself was recreated successfully but the data were missing.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of hits on Oracle Support; closest looks like bug 5574904. Bit hard to follow but possibly not fixed until 11.2.

The stated workaround is to either use `exp`/`imp` instead; or to drop the constraint in the schema you've imported too (since you've said it created the table), retry the `impdp` with additional parameters `tables=XP_ENTITIES_CONFIGS table_exists_action=append`, then recreate the constraint once the data has been imported.

Might well be something else though, so if in doubt raise a service request with Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

**CHECK YOUR FILES' CHECKSUM!**

I had a file corruption issue moving dump files between servers.  Took a long time to figure out I had corrupted a file.